# Minecraft Lag Spikes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I already have Optifine installed, and I've tried doing lower resolution resource packs, turning down my settings, and all that. I also know that I can allocate more RAM to Minecraft, but I only have 2 GB of RAM. I have allocated some more RAM in MB instead, however, max RAM isn't really the problem. The thing is that I randomly take lag spikes, or my computer beeps at me and doesn't allow me to do anything for 2-3 seconds, which is REALLY bad when you're in the middle of a PVP battle. I already know about the RAM, Optifine, and Priority. But I still get lag spikes, and something I seem to can't control, is the computer beeping at me and not allowing me to do anything at completely random times.

So I was just wondering if there was at least a way to stop the beeping, or both the lag spikes and beeping.

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate

Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 3800+ 2.00 GHz

RAM: 2.00 GB

SystemType: 64-bit

Comment: 2GB of Ram with Windows 7? There's your problem; W7 takes that up all by itself.

Comment: I'm with Frank on this one. And even if, somehow, W7 isn't using it all up, there's also the possibility of background applications running as well. As for the beeping, I don't see that being something we can deal with without dealing with the other issues first.

Comment: The beeping might be the keyboard that indicates that you are changing the state of too many buttons at once. I don't have a gaming keyboard, so I experience that too. I just release all the keys for a moment and then I can continue.

Comment: to be fair, minecraft pc version is very non reliable performance wise.. I find that increasing render distance to 14 make it lag way less than leaving it at 8. Also, set the priority to bellow normal, dunno why, but it solves the mouse lag spike, found about that in a youtube vid where lots of ppl have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Frank's comment, I've done more research and found that many users have a RAM issue with Windows 7 because the OS will take up most of it on launch. [Here](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/62848-63-windows-memory-usage) is one of those users. This specific person loses 1.6GB to the OS.

You must have a lot of RAM left over if you want to not experience lag spikes in Minecraft, or any game. Once you get more RAM or upgrade to Windows 10, you should no longer experience these lag spikes.